# 'a0' character in mysql

Tags: mysql, character, ascii

I have this column in my MySQL database. It is of type TINYTEXT. I fetch this column with a PHP script and displays it in an HTML. I find that all of my text has a trailing character in it. It shows up as a question mark with a diamond behind it in the browser.

I opened MySQL workbench and selected the column into the editor. I opened the value in the editor. The words seemed normal, except that they all have a trailing space behind it. I also took a look at the binary tab and the last group of letter/numbers is always 'a0'.

What could this be? I tried to trim the title, replace '\r' with '', replace '\n' with '', but nothing seem to work. How do I get rid of this? I also tried replacing '\xa0', though I don't know what this does (one of the solutions google turned up). But it does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Its probably a non-breaking space (&nbsp;). Replacing with "\xA0" should work if the string literal is in PHP,C,Java,etc. for SQL try `CHAR(0xA0)`. I'm assuming you are using a non-unicode charset.

Comment: Replacing CHAR(0xA0) with '' does not work...